# Pdf shows grey screen at first but loads the content after refresh in IE11

Tags: pdf, internet-explorer, http-headers, pdf-generation, browser-cache

I am generating pdf using XSLT.Facing two issues:
1) Opened one pdf and closed and tried to open another pdf shows the same old pdf content: Looked for a solution and implemented this:

```
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        response.setHeader("Expires", "0"); // Proxies.
```

But this solution is creating another problem now,now the pdf shows grey screen at first and after a refresh it loads the page.

Any suggestions how to solve this? Thanks In Advance

Comment: How do you generate the PDF file and how do you display the PDF file, can you share the related code? Whether this problem only occurs in IE browser or not? Try to use F12 developer Network tools to check whether the pdf file is loaded completely.

Comment: I am generating the pdf using FOP and display it on web browser only.And you are right it occurs only in IE and works smoothly in chrome.

Comment: Can't not reproduce the problem on my side, can you tell us the detail steps to reproduce the problem? Besides, please try to clear the browser data (cache and history) or using the other pdf file to check whether it works well. Here is an article about [How to display PDF in HTML](http://jsgyan.blogspot.com/2017/12/how-to-display-pdf-in-html-web-page.html), you could refer to it.

Comment: I am generating pdf using iframe only and it is embedded in html.
The first time when it shows grey screen,i saw in developer tools that it shows In progress ,thus the pdf is not loaded and after a refresh it shows status OK

Answer (score 0):

> The first time when it shows grey screen,i saw in developer tools that
>   it shows In progress ,thus the pdf is not loaded and after a refresh
>   it shows status OK

Perhaps the pdf file is a little big, and needs some time to load, so, we could wait the pdf file load success, then it will display in the Browser.

Besides, you could also try to clear the browser data (such as cache, cookie and history) to improve the browser performance.

Comment: Its not the case...first time it is hanging and then when you click refresh then it is loading th epage,sometimes it takes more than one refresh.

Comment: Can you tell us the PDF file size? Try to use the source: "http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf", when I tested it on my side, it will show  a grey screen at first, after one or two seconds it will display the pdf file. So, I  think perhaps the issue is related to the pdf file size, we need to wait the pdf file load success.

Comment: Actually in my application,we have some 14 pdfs and some are big but some are small .This behavior is for all the pdfs.

Comment: You could try to create a new page which only contains one pdf file, and check whether the IE browser browser works well, it it still doesn't working, perhaps the issue is related to the IE browser setting, try to clear browser cache and [reset the IE browser setting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings). If it displays well, perhaps the issue is that the web page contains two much pdf files, and it will reduce the browser performance.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue when creating a PDF file on the server and redirecting the browser straight to its URL. What seems to have fixed it was, instead of redirecting from the backend, writing

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf" />
```

to my response (substitute the URL of your PDF file). That way, it is the browser that redirects itself after the response has been completed and received.

More info [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html).